# Can't transfer files to Galaxy S3 from laptop, Kies not getting Installed on laptop

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, file-transfer, samsung-kies, usb-mass-storage

I have a Samsung Galaxy S3 on Android 4.1.1 Jelly Bean. I can't connect it to my Windows XP laptop. When I connect it with a USB cable, it's not getting mounted and thus I'm unable to transfer any files.

On my laptop, Samsung Kies is not installed, hope it may be the problem. But my laptop, Kies is not getting installed, it's showing "no internet connected!!" even if I am connected to WiFi.

I am totally stuck, please can anyone help?

Comment: What OS are you running on your laptop? Which Android version is it on your S3? Have you checked the USB connection mode it uses (UMS, PTP, MTP)? I don't think Kies will help (except for slowing down your Laptop, there's not much it can do good as far as I've read).

Comment: laptop-Windows xp,Android Galaxy s3-4.1.1(jelly bean),Can you please help me, how to set this USB(UMS, PTP, MTP) connection mode??

Comment: I have neither Windows nor an S3. But seeing it uses 4.1+ it most likely will support MTP (and AFAIK Windows-Explorer should be able to handle that). When you connected the USB cable, open the notification area. It should have an entry with the USB icon. Tapping that should allow you to chose the connection mode. I guess your default setting says "charge-only", which is why it doesn't appear to mount on your laptop.

Comment: And also i cant find USB utilities in my Android Phone.Its running in Android 4.1.1 jellybean how can i locate usb utils\????

Comment: What should "USB Utils" be? There might be something like "USB Settings". Checking with my *LG-P880*, there's one fitting place: *Settings->Connections->USB-Connection*. Here I can chose the connection mode, and define it to always ask me what to do when a connection is established. Might be at the same/a similar place on your SGS3.

Comment: The problem is, in GS3(Jellybean 4.1.1) there no option called "Connections" or "USB Connections". Also there is no option "USb Utilities".I had gone through the complete settings. I cant find a way to set USB connection mode.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need the KIES USB driver in order for Windows XP to recognise your phone. This feature is already built into Windows 7 and above by default and doesn't need any external driver software.

You don't need all the KIES software just the single file USB driver. Google it (the driver) and install it.

Kies3Setup.exe 42 806 KB

That how I got my Samsungs to be recognised by my Windows XP PC.

Answer (score 0):

Select the 'Mass Storage Only' option in the USB settings and then connect the cable.

If this doesn't work, you can connect your laptop and your phone to the same wireless network and use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid) to transfer files wirelessly from your laptop to your phone and vice versa using a browser on your laptop. Both devices just have to be connected to the same wireless network (with or without internet access).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it fast enough to transfer file fast???i had heard about this.....but still these kies are not getting istalled to lap???

Comment: Depends on what you think is fast enough! I got similar speeds while transferring files through a USB cable and through AirDroid. You don't need kies for using AirDroid. Give a shot. Something is better than nothing!

Comment: yup thats correct will surely give a try and will let you about this...soon

Comment: @Ambar May I know where I can access the 'Mass Storage Only' option in the USB settings you mentioned? Is it available on Galaxy S4? Thank you!

Comment: @Han I am not too familiar with the Galaxy S4 but it seems like people cannot enable the Mass Storage Only option in this particular phone. Hope you find a solution soon! Cheers